# Converse of Geometric mean theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle C=90^\circ$
and $h$ be it's altitude and $p,q$ be the lines it creates on the hypotenuse $AB$. The geometric mean theorem states that $h^2=pq$. On wikipedia there is a converse of the theorem that states that if $h^2=pq$ with the notations above, then $\angle C=90^\circ$.
I am however interested in a different kind of converse(conjecture): Let $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle C=90^\circ$, and let  $D\in [AB]$, show that if  $CD^2=AD\cdot DB$, then $CD$ is the altitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjecture :

> Let $\triangle ABC$ with $C=90^∘$, and let $D∈[AB]$. If $CD^2=AD⋅DB$, then $CD$ is the altitude.

is false. The simplest counterexample is : let $D$ be the midpoint of hypotenuse $AB$. Then $D$ is center of circle through $A,B,C$. So that $CD=AD=BD=$ radius of this (circum)circle.

Indeed $CD^2=AD\cdot DB$, but $CD$ is not the altitude (except for the special case of isosceles right triangle).